QGIS Global Variables Editing
I am trying to clean out some of the variables that I have created over time, but QGIS won't allow me to edit or delete any of the user define Global Variables

From the GQIS documentation, it looks like all you should need to do is use the '-' symbol to delete.  Need help with what I am over looking.


You seem to be in the wrong place. You are trying to remove them through the project settings at: Project|Properties.
But these global variables can only be removed in the general settings under: Settings|Options|Variables.
